# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir dos returns de una función en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi problema se que es sencillo pero no se como resolverlo, lo unico que necesito es agregar una celda temporal donde muestre el isr y el sueldoneto en la tabla empleado pero no logro que lo imprime, no se si el return se tenga que hacer de otra manera, tengo que hacerlo con una sola funcion no puedo poner dos

Codigo:

```
create function f_isr(@SueldoBase decimal(15,2),@LimInf decimal(15,2),@LimSup decimal(15,2),@CuotaFija decimal(15,2),@Porcentaje decimal(15,2))

returns decimal(15,2)
as begin

declare @uno decimal(15,2)

declare @dos decimal(15,2)

declare @tres decimal(15,2)

declare @isr decimal(15,2)

declare @suelneto decimal(15,2)

set @uno=(@SueldoBase-@LimInf)

set @dos=@uno*(@Porcentaje/100)

set @tres=@CuotaFija+@dos

set @isr=@tres

set @suelneto=@SueldoBase-@isr

return @isr  return @suelneto

end
```

aquí es donde tiene que mostrar los dos campos pero no me deja de esta manera, si alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo se lo agradecería:

```
select 
NomEmpleado, CorreoEmp, TelEmp,SueldoBase,э
LimInf,LimSup,CuoFija,Porcentaje, 
dbo.f_isr(SueldoBase,LimInf,LimSup,CuoFija,Porcentaje) as ISR,
SuedoNeto
from EMPLEADO
```

Answer (score 1):

El `RETURN` es único por función, lo que si podrías hacer es reemplazar el dato de retorno, en vez de un numérico escalar, puedes retornar una tabla con dos columnas correspondientes a los valores que buscas devolver. Haciendo esto estás creando una [función tipo tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-multi-statement-table-valued-function)

```
create function f_isr(@SueldoBase decimal(15,2),
                      @LimInf     decimal(15,2),
                      @LimSup     decimal(15,2),
                      @CuotaFija  decimal(15,2),
                      @Porcentaje decimal(15,2))
returns @OutputTable TABLE(
           isr      decimal(15,2),
           suelneto decimal(15,2)
        )
as begin

    declare @uno decimal(15,2)
    declare @dos decimal(15,2)
    declare @tres decimal(15,2)
    declare @isr decimal(15,2)
    declare @suelneto decimal(15,2)

    set @uno=(@SueldoBase-@LimInf)
    set @dos=@uno*(@Porcentaje/100)
    set @tres=@CuotaFija+@dos
    set @isr=@tres
    set @suelneto=@SueldoBase-@isr

    insert into @OutputTable(isr, suelneto)
           values (@isr, @suelneto)

    return
end
```

---

Definimos que el retorno sea una variable tipo tabla, con dos columna: `@OutputTable` y simplemente debemos insertar los valores en la misma antes de salir de la función.

Finalmente para invocarla (Esto es un ejemplo):

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
   SueldoBase   NUMERIC(15,2),
   LimInf       NUMERIC(15,2),
   LimSup       NUMERIC(15,2),
   CuotaFija    NUMERIC(15,2),
   Porentaje    NUMERIC(15,2)
)
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (SueldoBase, LimInf, LimSup, CuotaFija, Porentaje)
     VALUES(100, 10, 90, 10, 10)
  
SELECT *
       FROM Ejemplo T
       CROSS APPLY dbo.f_isr(T.SueldoBase, T.LimInf, T.LimSup, T.CuotaFija, T.Porentaje) C

SueldoBase  LimInf  LimSup  CuotaFija   Porentaje   isr  suelneto
100.00       10.00   90.00      10.00       10.00   19.00   81.00
```

Comment: ok me sirvió de mucho igual, pero tengo que imprimir los datos de esa función junto con la tabla empleado, lo intenten con un join pero no me funciono, igual con los datos que tiene la tabla empleado, se tienen que hacer las operaciones se necesitan en la funcion anexo el codigo:

Comment: CREATE TABLE empleado
(
NomEmpleado varchar(50),
CorreoEmp varchar (50),
TelEmp bigint,
SueldoBase decimal(15,2),
LimInf decimal(15,2),
LimSup decimal(15,2),
CuoFija decimal(15,2),
Porcentaje decimal(15,2)
)

drop table EMPLEADO

insert into EMPLEADO(NomEmpleado ,CorreoEmp ,TelEmp ,SueldoBase ,LimInf ,LimSup ,CuoFija ,Porcentaje) 
values('Erick Rios','erick.rios@gmail.com','6641564879',25000.00,24222.32,38177.69,3880.44,23.52)

Comment: Acabo de dejarte un ejemplo de como se usa la función con otra tabla de dónde obtener los datos.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me funciono, la verdad que me ayudo mucho